# MySQL : How to lock all write in all databases?

Tags: linux, replication, mysql5.5, block, read-only

I need to block all writes (insert , update, delete) on all databases.
How can I do that ?
Put all database in Read Only for a period time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick [search](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=mysql%205.5%20read-only) results in the correct chapter of the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-solutions-backups-read-only.html) with:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
mysql> SET GLOBAL read_only = ON;
```